# Extension of Linear Operatos

Tags: banach-spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do continuous linear functions between Banach spaces extend?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96739/do-continuous-linear-functions-between-banach-spaces-extend)

Is there an example of a pair of Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$, a subspace $E\subseteq X$ and a bounded linear operator $T:E\rightarrow Y$ (with the norm on $E$ induced by the norm on $X$) such that there doesn't exist an extension $\hat T:X\rightarrow Y$ of $T$?