# Is duality an exact functor on Banach spaces or Hilbert spaces?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, category-theory, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let $V,V',V''$ and $W$ be vector spaces over $k$. Then, it is known that $\operatorname{Hom}(\cdot,V)$ is a contravariant exact functor, i.e. for each exact sequence

$0\to V'\to V\to V'' \to 0$,

and each $W$, the induced sequence

$0\to \operatorname{Hom}(V'',W)\to\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)\to\operatorname{Hom}(V',W)\to 0$

is exact.

But what if all spaces involved are Banach spaces (over $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$) and if we replace $\operatorname{Hom}(\cdot,V)$ by $\operatorname{L}(\cdot,V)$, i.e. the *continuous* linear maps with domain $V$? Is this functor still exact? What if we restict ourselves even stronger to Hilbert spaces? I'm particularly interested in the specialization of $W=\mathbb{R}$ or $W=\mathbb{C}$, where we get the dual spaces (again, only *continuous* maps considered in the Banach- or Hilbert case).

I'm learning for an exam and the books I've been reading say nothing about it...

Thank you!

Comment: In your first paragraph you write $\textrm{Hom}(V, \cdot)$ but describe $\textrm{Hom}(\cdot, W)$. There's a similar problem in your second paragraph.

Comment: Hint for $W = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$: yes. Use Hahn-Banach. No for general $W$: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/96739/

Comment: @Martin: This is not a comment, this is an answer.

Comment: @Martin: Ok, will expand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To say that$\DeclareMathOperator{Hom}{Hom}$
$$
0 \to V' \xrightarrow{i} V \xrightarrow{p} V'' \to 0
$$
is exact is equivalent to saying that $i$ is a kernel of $p$ and $p$ is a cokernel of $i$. This amounts to the automatic exactness of
$$
0 \to \Hom(W,V') \xrightarrow{i_\ast}\Hom(W,V) \xrightarrow{p_\ast} \Hom(W,V'')
$$
and
$$
0 \to \Hom(V'',W) \xrightarrow{p^\ast} \Hom(V,W) \xrightarrow{i^\ast} \Hom(V',W)
$$
for all Banach spaces $W$ where I write $\Hom(V,W) = L(V,W)$ for the space of *continuous* linear maps.

---

Consider the special case $W = \mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$):

Giving a morphism $f \colon \mathbb R \to X$ is the same as choosing a vector $x = f(1) \in X$ because for a scalar $\lambda$ we have $f(\lambda) = f(\lambda 1) = \lambda f(1) = \lambda x$. So: $\Hom(\mathbb R, X) = X$ for every Banach space and the sequence
$$
0 \to \Hom(\mathbb R,V') \xrightarrow{i_\ast}\Hom(\mathbb R,V) \xrightarrow{p_\ast} \Hom(\mathbb R,V'') \to 0
$$
really is the sequence $0 \to V' \xrightarrow{i} V \xrightarrow{p} V'' \to 0$ we started with.

Since $\operatorname{im} i = \ker{p}$, the map $i\colon V' \to V$ is a homeomorphism onto its range $i(V')$ and $i(V')$ is a closed subspace of $V$. A linear map $f' \colon V' \to \mathbb R$ thus corresponds to a linear functional on the subspace $i(V')$ of $V$ and the Hahn-Banach theorem allows us to extend that linear functional to all of $V$. In other words, $i^\ast \colon \Hom(V,\mathbb R) \to \Hom(V',\mathbb R)$ is always surjective and therefore the dual sequence
$$
0 \to (V'')^\ast \to V^\ast \to (V')^\ast \to 0
$$
is exact.

---

For general Banach spaces $W$, the answer is that neither $p_\ast$ nor $i^\ast$ need to be surjective: For $V' = c_0$ and $V = \ell_\infty$ and $V'' = \ell_\infty / c_0$, the sequence 
$$
0 \to c_0 \xrightarrow{i} \ell_\infty \xrightarrow{p} \ell_\infty/c_0 \to 0
$$
is exact. *Phillips' lemma* says that for $W = c_0$ the identity $V' \to W$ cannot be extended to a morphism $V = \ell_\infty \to c_0$ and, equivalently, the identity $\ell_\infty/c_0 \to V''$ cannot be lifted to $\ell_\infty/c_0 \to \ell_\infty$.

See

- [Do continuous linear functions between Banach spaces extend?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/96739/)
- [Complement of $c_{0}$ in $\ell^{\infty}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/132520/)

for proofs and further discussion of this last point.

Comment: I decided to leave the Hilbert space case to you. The answer is yes and I can expand in case you are stuck.

Comment: I guess there is a question as to how exactly you define the category of Banach spaces.  It seems that you are considering the category whose morphisms are continuous linear maps with closed images, in which case the cokernel of a morphism is just the image of the map.  But it is perhaps more natural to let the morphisms be *all* the continuous linear maps, in which case the cokernel of a morphism should be the *closure* of the image.  This changes the answer for $L(\cdot, \mathbb{R})$, which I'll address in another answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge: no I'm using *all* the continuous linear maps. The morphisms with closed image do not form a category since they are not closed under composition. Why do you think that it seems that I use just those morphisms which are continuous linear maps with closed images?

Comment: Notice that $0 \to V' \to V \to V'' \to 0$ *exact* means that $i$ is injective, $i(V) = \ker{p}$ and $p$ is surjective, so $i$ has automatically closed image (by exactness at $V$) and $p$ is (isomorphic to) the projection $V \to V/i(V')$, hence it is onto.

Comment: I'm sorry, my category theory is really bad.  You are right about the morphisms being all continuous linear maps.  But what I mean is this: I would say that $0 \to V' \to V \to V'' \to 0$ being short exact should mean that $\operatorname{coker} i = \ker p$ and $\operatorname{coker} p = 0$.  I believe the cokernel of a map $i$ should be, not its image (which need not be a Banach space if it is not closed), but the closure of its image.  This means in order for the sequence to be exact, we only need that $\overline{(i(V))} = \ker p$ and $p$ has dense image.

Comment: I see what you mean. Notice that you are really talking about the categorical *image*, not the cokernel of $i$ when you say "$\operatorname{coker} i = \ker{p}$". The cokernel of a map $f \colon V \to W$ is the (projection on the) quotient $V/\overline{f(W)}$ and the categorical image is the kernel of the cokernel (i.e. taking the closure of the image). In that case we seem to disagree about what notion of exactness one should use: you are saying one should use the Banach interpretation of "$\ker p = \operatorname{im} i$" while I think one should use the algebraic factorization properties.

Comment: Yes, that's a much better way of saying what I mean.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks, Martin and Nate!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to adjust your notation, because $V'$ looks too much like a dual space to me.

In the category of Banach spaces, where the morphisms are the continuous linear maps, one should perhaps interpret "image" in the categorical sense, as the *closure* of the image.  (See the comments on Martin's answer.)  If we interpret "exact" according to this sense, then  a sequence $$0 \to X_1 \overset{S}{\to} X_2 \overset{T}{\to} X_3 \to 0$$ is exact iff $\ker S = 0$, $\overline{S(X_1)} = \ker T$, and $T(X_2)$ is dense in $X_3$.

In this setting, the functor $L(\cdot, W)$ is not exact, not even when $W = \mathbb{R}$.  For instance, let's take $X_1 = \ell^1$, $X_2 = \ell^2$, $S$ the inclusion map, and $X_3 = 0$.  Since $S$ is injective and has dense image, this sequence is exact.  If $L(\cdot, \mathbb{R})$ were an exact functor, then $S^* : (\ell^2)^* \to (\ell_1)^*$ should also be injective and have dense image.  $S^*$ is injective,  but since it is a map from the separable Banach space $(\ell^2)^* = \ell^2$ to the non-separable Banach space $(\ell^1)^* = \ell^\infty$, it cannot have dense image.  (In fact, $S^*$ is just the inclusion map $\ell^2 \to \ell^\infty$ and the closure of $\ell^2$ in $\ell^\infty $ is $c_0$, the sequences which vanish at infinity.)

If you work in the category of *reflexive* Banach spaces, then $L(\cdot, \mathbb{R})$ is an exact functor; this is a fairly straightforward diagram chase using the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: With exact being interpreted in the categorical sense, is $L(.,\mathbb{C})$ exact?

Comment: @ChrisLeary: The answer should be no, with pretty much the same counterexample.  But do you have in mind to work in the category of complex Banach spaces, or real?

Comment: I want to work with complex Banach spaces. More specifically, my concern is only with one-to-one or onto transformations, so I think Martin's argument is more what I need. I am working with continuous transformations from convergent sequences in one Banach space to conservative sequences in a second Banach space that is weakly sequentially complete (so, with conservative transformations in generalized summability). We have the continuous linear transformation $\chi(T)$ that maps between the underlying Banach spaces. Several results I have rely on ...

Comment: ... $\chi(T)$ being one-to-one or onto. My concern with your and Martin's answer was in trying to find an example of a Hopfian Banach space (onto continuous implies one-to-one) by using the dual of a known co-Hopfian Banach space (continuous one-to-one implies onto). Having said that, there is benefit to the categorical approach you mention and the statement you make about reflexive Banach spaces, since some of my results concern conservative maps between sequences in finite dimensional complex vector spaces.  Thanks for responding to my question, I appreciate it very much.